# Is there a way to disable middle-click=paste in LyX

Tags: lyx

I use LyX 2.0.0rc3 on Mac OS X. Like on other systems, it automatically maps middle-click to paste, which on my hardware leads to numerous accidental pastes of gobs of text.

Is anyone aware of a way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: This is nothing you can disable it in LyX, you need to configure your Window-System. On X-Window you may be able to map middle-mouse-click to something else, but I'm not sure of Mac OS X.

Comment: Lyx is built on top of Qt, which handles translation of keyboard and mouse events into the form that Lyx understands.  It should be possible to tell Qt to change how it handles middle-clicks, but this is outside what I know.  I guess you will get a better answer on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ - if you do ask, it would be interesting for me if you posted a link to your new question here.

Comment: This is definitely related to LyX. Nowhere in OS X does middle cick mean pasting.

Comment: Are you using native OS X version of LyX, or one which uses the X server?  Paste with middle click is typically a feature of an X server, not an application.

Comment: @Jan: Please convert your comment into an answer so that this question can be removed from the "Unanswered" list.

Answer (score 4):

As of LyX 2.2 there will be a preference to control middle button click behavior. Middle click is disabled by default for Mac and Windows users.

The fix was by Jürgen Spitzmüller and can be seen here:
http://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/d48e5330/lyxgit

Answer (score 1):

(Originally posted as a comment by jan Hlavacek)

Are you using native OS X version of LyX, or one which uses the X server? Paste with middle click is typically a feature of an X server, not an application.

Answer (score 0):

It was done in the last LyX update.

They added a new option to disable pasting by pressing the middle mouse button.

See:

http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX22

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer